Is it possible to tell apt to stop prompting about certain missing dependencies?
I have a scanner that only works when downloading the .deb from the manufacturer (Brother) and installing with:
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libsane-dsseries_1.0.5-1_amd64.deb

--force-all is required. Without it, it won't install due to an unmet dependency (libsane (>= 1.0.17)).
Now when I install anything with apt, I get messages about the unmet dependency and using --fix-broken removes the scanner driver.
I've solved it by finding libsane and installing it, but that might not always be an option.
Is it possible to somehow tell apt to ignore the dependency/suppress the error so I can continue to install other packages?

Yes, you can stop apt from prompting about certain missing dependencies by using options like ignore missing to bypass missing packages or no install recommends to avoid installing optional ones. Additionally, you can globally disable recommended or suggested packages by modifying the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d configuration file.

It's unfortunate that you have not properly spelled out the names of the actual options; but moreover, this is really off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. They should ask on [unix.se] instead.

Thanks Dheeraj. The actual options seem to be --no-install-recommends and --ignore-missing.
@tripleee: That's correct. I should've asked it in Unix & Linux. My mistake!
